# PHP code inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to see how can I get the $CITY, $STATE, and $count data to be included in the javascript code ?

Here is the non working code:

```
<?php echo('<script type="text/javascript"> var address$count = $CITY$STATE');?>

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       zoom: 6
   });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({'address': address<?php echo($count);?>},

   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
   });

   </script> 
<?php
}
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "apart" or "a part"? They mean two opposite things. Also, please do not use non-words like "probpem" to get around que question title filter. Please edit your title into something more informative.

Comment: @bfavaretto I edited the question, I did not know that the word problem was a non-word, it was just a spelling mistake I did not try to get around anything. But it's still good to know what words I can use in the title, Thank you.

Comment: My apologies then. I too believed it was a typo, but when I tried to fix it myself, the system didn't let me save the title because of the word "problem". So I just assumed it happened to you too, and that you intentionally tried do get around the filter. Sorry if I was rude.

Comment: @bfavaretto no, you where not rude, you took the time to read my title/question and this also helps me get a better response and hopefully an answer, so no worries and thank you for your input/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables are correct, javascript usually needs quotes around strings, like so:

```
<?php 
 echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var address'.$count.' = "'.$CITY.$STATE.'"';
?>
```

Also, to use PHP variables inside a string would require double quotes, so if you intend to keep the single quotes you would need to concentenate.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var address".$count." = "".$CITY." ".$STATE."";" ;?>

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       zoom: 6
   });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({'address': address<?php echo($count);?>},

   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
   });

   </script> 
<?php
}
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php echo('
   <script type="text/javascript"> var address' . $count . '= "' . $CITY . $STATE . '"'
);?>
```